# Append to Bootstrap Bootbox Confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, prepend, bootbox

I've been playing around with bootbox and am currently using a bootstrap.confirm dialog to confirm a user action. However i would like my dialog to have a title and a close button (preference really)

Heres my code for boot box

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected task?", function(result) {
    if (result == true) {
       //do something           
    }
});
```

And the code to append a title

```
$(".bootbox").prepend("<div class=\"modal-header\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"close\">&times;</a><h3>Confirm Delete</h3></div>");
```

Problem is i dont know how to get it to fire before the dialog loads. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this one out

```
$("body").on("show", ".bootbox", function () {
    /* Dont add header again if div has been added */
    if (!$(".modal-header")[0]) {
        $(".bootbox").prepend("<div class=\"modal-header\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"close\">&times;</a><h3>Confirm Delete</h3></div>");
    }
});
```

Basically prepend is called as the bootbox is launched, so by the time the modal is visible the title has been added. Also had to add a check to make sure the title is only appended once